# unset() from array versus if inside loop?

Tags: php

I'm making a pagination script. As part of it, it will need to reconstruct the query string, minus `$_GET['page']`.

This is option 1:

```
#reconstruct the GETs minus $_GET['page']
$vars = $_GET;
unset($vars['page']);
$queryString = '';
foreach ($vars as $k=>$v){
    $queryString .= '&amp;'.$k.'='.$v;
}
```

This is option 2:

```
$vars = $_GET;
$queryString = '';
foreach ($vars as $k=>$v){
    if ($k !== 'page'){
        $queryString .= '&amp;'.$k.'='.$v;
    }
}
```

Is one better than the other in terms of either speed or good practice? Presumably `unset` would be marginally quicker, as it would stop as soon as it found what it was looking for whereas the other would perform the `if` for every loop?

Additionally, when initializing the `$queryString` is there a reason to choose `NULL` over empty string or does it make no difference to anything?

Comment: I'd say the differences are negligeble and you're wasting time on microoptimization.

Comment: I agree, however if I hadn't posed the question I would never have found out about `http_build_query()`! It's also probably a good idea to implement best practices no matter what the scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do neither. Use [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query).

> Generates a URL-encoded query string from the associative (or indexed) array provided.

When working with such small loops, speed considerations are absolutely meaningless. Code readability comes above everything!

`NULL` is identical to an empty string, so it's down to taste which one you want to use.

Comment: As is blatantly obvious from the question I had no idea that existed! There's probably an awful lot of things in PHP that you just don't discover until someone tells you about them.

Comment: @mcmcfc true! I didn't know about http_build_query() for years, either.

Comment: I also accidentally discovered that function some time ago. But on this time it was too late for many projects :)

Answer (score 2):

You might also use the [http_build_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.http-build-query.php) function for that. Try something like this:

```
$vars = $_GET;
unset($vars ['page']);
$queryString = http_build_query($vars , '', '&amp;');
```